# Using a lookup table using google guava

Tags: hashmap, guava, lookup-tables

I am new to Java. I have a requirement of holding a lookup table in memory(Abbreviations and their expansions). I was thinking of using Java Hash map. But I want to know if that really is the best approach.
Also, If there are any equivalent libraries in Google Guava, for the same requirement.
I want it to me optimized and very efficient w.r.t time and memory

Comment: Guava defines collections that are not already present in the standard collections. If you want a single value for each key, then use a HashMap. If you want multiple values for a single key, then use a Guava Multimap. It uses a HashMap internally anyway.

Comment: If you're trying to optimize things like this at this stage of the game, you've already lost.  Only optimize after you have actually built a first version and have hard numbers indicating that the performance is inadequate.

Comment: You won't find in Guava map implementations that are equivalent to their JDK counterparts, but with greatly improved performance. You will find Map implementations that complement the JDK implementations.

There's a few questions you can use to restrict the available implementations to a few choices. Do you need a mutable or immutable map? Does the insertion order needs to be preserved? Does the map needs ordering on its keys? Is it a map that will be modified by concurrent threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using [Maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Maps are indeed fine for this, as used below.

Apparently, it's a bit early for you to care that much about performance or memory consumption though, and we can't really help you if we don't have more context on the actual use case.

#### In Pure Java

```
final Map<String, String> lookup = new HashMap<>();

lookup.put("IANAL", "I Ain't A Lawyer");
lookup.put("IMHO", "In My Humble Opinion");
```

Note that there are [several implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html) of the [Map interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), or that you can write your own.

#### Using Google Guava

If you want an immutable map:

```
final Map<String, String> lookup = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
    .put("IANAL", "I Ain't A Lawyer")
    .put("IMHO", "In My Humble Opinion")
    .build();
```

#### Retrieving Data

Then to use it to lookup an abbreviation:

```
// retrieval:
if (lookup.containsKey("IMHO")) {
  final String value = lookup.get("IMHO");

  /* do stuff */
}
```

---

### Using [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

I was speaking of alternatives...

If you know at coding time what the key/value pairs will be, you may very well be better off using a Java enum:

```
class Abbrevations {
  IANAL  ("I Ain't A Lawyer")
  IMHO   ("In My Humble Opinion");

  private final String value;

  private Abbreviations(final String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return (value);
  }

}
```

You can then lookup values directly, ie either by doing this:

```
Abbreviations.IMHO.getValue()
```

Or by using:

```
Abbreviations.valueOf("IMHO).getValue()
```

---

Considering where you seem to be in your learning process, I'd recommend you follow the links and read through the Java tutorial and implement the examples.